# Relationship beween SEs of two point estimates

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, standard-error, estimators

Good evening everybody!

There's a very odd question from an old exam in Introductory Statistics that has been preoccupying me for a couple ofhours:

What is the relationship between the Standard Errors of Theta Hat 1, Theta Hat 2 and the Sum of Theta Hat 1 and Theta Hat 2?

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Especially enlightening comments as to the sum of the two Thetas would be more than welcomed.

Comment: Until you can tell us more about the model, the data, and the roles of the $\theta_i$ in it, this question has many possible correct answers.  Presumably the question you are quoting has a context--perhaps it's one in a series of questions about a particular statistical setting?  What is that setting?

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks for your reply. The lack of context is what's been puzzling me to say the least. It's a very general question. Especially the sum of the point estimates strikes me as somewhat unusual.

Comment: I tried to think it through, though: that when one tries to estimate one parameter, that this will also affect the estimation of the other unknown parameter and also the Standard Error of the second estimator.

Comment: Yes, that's correct: the standard example concerns the Ordinary Least Squares estimates of linear regression.  But if, say, the $\theta_i$ are based on separate, independent datasets then (obviously) their standard errors will be independent, too.

Comment: Yep, but what am I supposed to do with the sum of two point estimates? I have been thinking that adding two different Theta Hats is equivalent to convoluting two different distributions, which should also yield another SE? Would you agree, Sir?